# is there a way to hide link if data-target not found?

Tags: javascript, jquery

can we hide link if data-target, not found

e.g:

```
<a class="navbar-toggle secondary" data-target=".region-header-right #block-secondarymenu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
<a class="navbar-toggle search" data-target=".region-header-right .block--type-search"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a>


<div id="#block-secondarymenu">something</div>
<div class="block--type-search">something</div>
```

can we hide `<a class="navbar-toggle search" data-target=".region-header-right .block--type-search"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a>`

if no `<div class="block--type-search">something</div>` data-target found on the page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: yes, (and simple with jQuery) you can itterate over the data-target and Looks, if the div.<data-target> exists. Did you include jQuery?

Comment: yes I have included jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way in vanilla javascript:

Get all the links

`var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');`

then check for each link if the data-target element is found on the page, and if it is not, then hide it:

```
for (l of links) {
    let selector = l.attributes["data-target"];
    if (!selector || !document.querySelector(selector.value)) {
        l.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Be aware that this doesn't check that the data-target refers to a single object in the page. To do that instead of `!document.querySelector(selector.value)` you can use `querySelectorAll` and check that the returned array has a length different than 1.

Answer (score 1):

In this example, only the second link will be shown, cause all Targets in this link exists.
https://jsfiddle.net/uyq725L4/

```
<a class="navbar-toggle secondary" data-target=".region-header-right #block-secondarymenu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Link #1</a>
<a class="navbar-toggle search" data-target=".region-header-right .block--type-search"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>Link #2</a>


<div id="#block-secondarymenu">something</div>
<div class="block--type-search">something</div>
<div class=".region-header-right">something</div>
```

and the javascript

```
jQuery(function(){
    var atags = jQuery('a').not('[data-target=""]');
  for (var i=0; i<atags.length;i++) {
    var targets = jQuery(atags[i]).data('target').split(" ");
    for (var j=0; j<targets.length; j++)
        if (jQuery(targets[i]).length===0) jQuery(atags[i]).hide();
  }
});
```